# In Wordpress CSS Styling @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) will not work

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, styling

When I am using

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    Height: 80%;
  }
}
```

The code does not work and defaults to original styling however the code works for

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  #imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    Height: 50%;
  }
}
```

all the way up to 1024px and then breaks
anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `max-width: 1024px` query must be placed **before** the `max-width: 425px` query in the code, otherwise, as an expected result of CSS specificity, overriding will occur.

**Demo of wrong order:**

```css
#imgWrapper {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative; }

#imgWrapper::after { content:"Default - Desktop/Large Screen"; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  #imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;  }
  #imgWrapper::after { content:"Max-425"; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;  }
  #imgWrapper::after { content:"Max-1024"; }
}
```

```html
<div id="imgWrapper">Media Query: </div>
```

**Proper order:**

```css
#imgWrapper {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative; }

#imgWrapper::after { content:"Default - Desktop/Large Screen"; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;  }
  #imgWrapper::after { content:"Max-1024"; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {
  #imgWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;  }
  #imgWrapper::after { content:"Max-425"; }
}
```

```html
<div id="imgWrapper">Media Query: </div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/d5bto8vL/

To conclude, media queries that are based on **desktop-first** model (`max-width` queries) should start with default styling for large screens then adding queries for lesser sizes, like so:

> large/default > 1024 > 768 > 425 etc

Whereas in a **mobile-first** model, you use `min-width` queries and the default styling is smallest then add bigger screens:

> small > 425 > 768 > 1024 etc